# why i can't alert this string which is return from django render_to_response

Tags: javascript, python, django

django code:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {
        "form": form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and  html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a='{{form}}'

       alert(a) 
</script>
```

it's error  is 'unterminated string literal',

and i see this in firebug :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a='"<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" type="text" class="textinput" name="username" maxlength="30" /></td></tr><tr><th><label for="id_email">Email (optional):</label></th><td><input id="id_email" type="text" class="textinput" name="email" /></td></tr>"';
            alert(a) 
    </script>
```

how do i alert the 'form' string .

thanks

Comment: Just checked out on local machine - everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try putting in semi-colons at the ends of the lines in your Django template file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a='{{form}}';

    alert(a);
</script>
```

Odd though, I’m pretty sure semi-colons are optional there. Could you do a View Source in Firefox (instead of looking via Firebug), and see what HTML is actually being output by Django?

Answer (score 1):

Check the HTML source of the page using "View source" rather than Firebug. I predict your `{{form}}` value has a line break in it, which will cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this error, pasting the above into a javascript console works without problems. Is it possible that there is something else done with `a`? Is above a simplification or exact javascript? Maybe you can show the entire HTML?